# Apply a function to a list that is a subset of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, map

My MMA fu is very stale, and I don't seem to be able to see a simple way to apply a function across a subset of a list.
Specifically in the following data, I want to apply `Max` to the second element of each pair in each line - hope that makes sense?:

```
lst={
{{100., 20.}, {99.7401, 19.7457}},
{{102., 22.}, {98.7401, 39.7457}},
{{103., 21.}, {97.7401, 49.7457}},
}
```

Ideally I'd expect the result to be

```
res={20.,39.7457, 49.7457}
```

Appreciate any hints tips or incantations.  These lists are large so I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to improve performance.

Comment: `Max[#[[All, -1]]] & /@ lst`?

Comment: apparently slightly faster than @J.M. 's suggestion: `Max /@ lst[[All, All, 2]]`

Comment: Generally `Query` is slow but it's convenient for hierarchical manipulations like this: `Query[All, Max, 2] @ lst`

Comment: Btw.: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks for the prompt responses.  All three of the suggestions worked.
The one that felt most familiar and apparently may be the fastest was:

```
Max /@ lst[[All, All, 2]]
```

The other approaches are worth collating just in case it helps anyone else:

```
Max[#[[All, -1]]] & /@ lst
Query[All, Max, 2] @ lst
```

Again thank you for the prompt and helpful responses.